# Angular FormGroup Cannot read property 'get' of undefined

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-forms

I am a bit newbie in Angular. I whant to make page with ability to add text inputs dynamicly.
I use FormGroup for this problem. Here is my code:

createInputDynamicly.ts

```
export class CreateInputsDynamicly implements OnInit {
  orderForm: FormGroup;
  items: FormArray;
  strings: string[];

  constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder) { }

  ngOnInit() {

    this.orderForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      items: this.formBuilder.array([ this.createItem() ])
    });
    this.strings.push('');
  }

  createItem(): FormGroup {
    return this.formBuilder.group({
      newText: ''
    });
  }


  addItem(): void {
    this.items = this.orderForm.get('items') as FormArray;
    this.items.push(this.createItem());
    this.strings.push('');
  }

  showString() {
    console.log(this.strings);
  }
}
```

createInputDynamicly.html

```
<div formArrayName="items"
  *ngFor="let item of orderForm.get('items').controls; let i = index;">
  <div [formGroupName]="i">
    <input formControlName="newText" [(ngModel)]="strings[i]">
  </div>
</div>

<button (click)="addItem()" type="button">Add new input</button>
<button (click)="showStrings()" type="button">Show</button>
```

The problem is that whenever I push "Add new input" button, I get "Cannot read property 'get' of undefined" in div and in add item method. I don't understand what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is the working example

in template

```
<form [formGroup]="orderForm">
<div formArrayName="items">
  <div [formGroupName]="i" *ngFor="let item of items.controls; let i = index;">
    <input formControlName="newText" >
  </div>
</div>

<button (click)="addItem()" type="button">Add new input</button>
<button (click)="showStrings()" type="button">Show</button>
</form>
```

in .ts

```
export class CreateInputsDynamicly implements OnInit {
  orderForm: FormGroup;
  get items(): FormArray {
    return this.orderForm.get("items") as FormArray;
  }

  constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.orderForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      items: this.formBuilder.array([ this.createItem() ])
    });

  }

  createItem(): FormGroup {
    return this.formBuilder.group({
      newText: ''
    });
  }


  addItem(): void {
    this.items.push(this.createItem());
  }

  showString() {
    console.log( this.items.value);
  }
}
```

1. Do not use formControlName and ngModel at time on one input
2. In your example `strings` is not defined it will give error
3. no need to have `strings` property you can get `this.orderForm.get('items').value`
4. Please make sure you have imported `OnInit` from `@angular/core`

Comment: It worked! Thank you very much! Also, I have question: why can't I use  formControlName and ngModel at time on one input? Just whant to know :)

Comment: it will call angular change detection twice.
it is equivalent to set the talue into the same input twice